# Visual graph editor with background image and export to code

Tags: java, data-visualization, graphs, cad, floor-plan

I need to draw graphs on top of floor plans to mark rooms and pathways and then export them to code (XML? JSON? Better in a database?) so I can turn the nodes and edges into properly connected Java objects. The features I need exported are: X and Y position on the canvas, name I provide, type I provide (room/hallway/stair/etc.), and of course the relationships between nodes.

I've tried yEd Graph Editor and it exports to .graphml, but the background image feature is static and not scrolling, so I can't use it to draw over a floor plan. I've also tried Autodesk Design Review on the .dwf version of my floor plan, but it doesn't export the coordinates of nodes and seems like it doesn't do most of what I want.

I will need to save the graphs in a graph format also so they can be adjusted later on and re-exported to code. Big bonus if the software lets me put nodes in 3D space so I can put all the floors of a building in one file and link floors by adding edges between stairs on adjacent floors. I'm going to look into Unity (the game engine) and Maya since they make it easy to draw in 3D space, but they might not give me the exporting functionality that I need.

Comment: Have you tried to make the background image dynamic in yEd? Does it still not scroll?

Comment: Didn't even see I could change that! Thanks.

Comment: yEd output turned out to be difficult to parse, so I'm trying JOSM, which is actually meant for mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) does just about everything I need. I can export as much data as I need by adding tags to nodes or ways. I can hide objects on a particular floor so I can draw overlapping nodes on a different floor of the building. The only problem with it is that you can't save a project file, so you can't close and reopen the program with your layer structure intact. The Session feature in expert mode kind of helps with this, but it doesn't work with PicLayers, so I have to re-add those every time I open the program.